# how to get rid of extra spaces below a page in MS word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, equations

I am writing equations in word using tables. My problem is, when the space below the page is insufficient for the equation, the equation goes to the next page and there is a blank space at the bottom of the page (as shown in the diagram below):

[image]

How shall I avoid this blank space? Should I write a single equation in a single cell in two separate pages? How shall I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behavior. When printing, it looks much better the way you see it now.

If you don't intend to print the document and just want to have optimal viewing, you can doubleclick between the two pages to remove any whitespace and make it all seem as one long page.

If printing is something you want to support, and you want things to look better, either change the margins of the page so they're larger, make the font smaller (or larger) or split the algebra writing into 2 or more objects.

Comment: Or consider using "keep with following" for the line before the equation.

Comment: @DavidPostill what do you mean?

Comment: To make "Following the rule ..." stay with the equation and not look so lonely all on it's own :)

Comment: You mean like placing a hard line break (ctrl+enter) before that row?

Comment: Ah. It should be "keep with next". [MS Word: Keep With Next vs Keep Lines Together](http://www.worldstart.com/ms-word-keep-with-next-vs-keep-lines-together/)

Comment: “Keep with next” is used to prevent Word from inserting automatic page breaks between paragraphs.

Comment: Ah, Keep with next. Yeah, agreed. thats a good alternative too.